# Parsing a CSV file with mutiple rows for one column and it is dynamic

Tags: java, excel, csv, parsing, multiple-columns

Now from the above image , I want to parse the data from csv/excel to the a *List owners*. Can someone help me on how to do that?

```
class Owner{
       String name;
       String address;
       List<Vehicle> vehicle;
}
class Vehicle{
       String number;
       double price;
}
```

I am aware I can use a Apache POI for parsing a Excel and Apache Commons for parsing a CSV. My major confusion is how to go ahead and read the file :
Eg: From seeing the image/file I can know that Kumar has four Vehicles but how to translate that to code :([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGsw6.png)

Input:
Name , Address , Vehicle , Price
Kumar, Bangalore,KA01AA1234,900300,
,          ,KA01AA1235,700300,
,          ,KA01AA1236,560300,
,          ,KA01AA1237,770300,
Suresh, Mangalore, KA20AA1234,900300,
,          ,KA20AA1235,700300,
,          ,KA20AA1236,560300,
Ramesh, Hosur, TN44AA1234,900300,
,          ,TN44AA1235,700300,
the input may not be very clear please click [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGsw6.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGsw6.png for better input view

Comment: Parsing an excel and parsing a CSV are different, what file type is it _actually_.  Also what have you tried to do?

Comment: @Nexevis for replying, https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGsw6.png if you check this image u will get an idea on what I am trying to do
I am trying to read a excel/csv file and map the data/values of the file to the object and return it as list of objects(list Owner objects)

->The actual issue is the below rows is empty but with only vehicle number and price how can I parse that in such way(the logic) that I can add all the vehicle to one owner were the Owner name is empty

Comment: Check for the presence of `Owner` name. If true, create `Owner` instance and add it to collection, then add `Vehicle` from same line to the `Owners`'s `Vehicle` collection. If false, add new `Vehicle` to current `Owners`'s `Vehicle` collection

Comment: @g00se, how would you code this for csv and excel

Comment: I'd let you do it

Comment: Please note that Excel is not CSV, and please don't conflate / confuse the two. What is the file extension?

Comment: @BigBen the input can be any of the file but the based on the file type the parsing takes place

Comment: @g00se okay, thank you